# Can I use uiRecordApi getRecord to get dynamically record?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-data-service, wire

Can I use `uiRecordApi` `getRecord` to get dynamically record?

I am developing a custom lightning web component which can be placed on different record pages (`Account`, `Contact`, and `Custom objects`).

I am trying to substitute the object name value dynamically but this doesn't work.

When I try to use this code

```
@api objectApiName;

FIELDS = [
    this.objectApiName + '.Name'
];
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: '$FIELDS'}) //, fields: `$objectApiName.Name`
wiredGetRecord({ error, data }) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
    debugger;
    if (data) {
        this.record = data;
        this.error = undefined;
        this.title = 'New Agreement for ' + this.record.fields.Name.value;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.record = undefined;
    }
}
record;
```

I see two different errors

1)

```
aura_proddebug.js:5163 Error: [LWC error]: Can’t read the value of property `objectApiName` from the constructor because the owner component hasn’t set the value yet. Instead, use the constructor to set a default value for the property.
```

2. 

```
"The "fields" query string parameter contained object api names that do not correspond to the api names of any of the requested record ids. The requested object api names were: [undefined], while the requested records had object types: [Contract]"
```

When I use another code

```
objectName = '$objectApiName';
FIELDS = [
    this.objectName + '.Name'
];
```

I see another error

```
"The "fields" query string parameter contained object api names that do not correspond to the api names of any of the requested record ids. The requested object api names were: [$objectApiName], while the requested records had object types: [Contract]"
```

Is this possible to get this working using Lightning Data Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not possible to achieve with Lightning Data Service.

A custom Apex method and imperative Apex should be used to get this done.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static SObject getRecord(Id recordId, String objectApiName) {
    return Database.query('SELECT Name FROM ' + objectApiName ' + WHERE Id = \'' + recordId + '\'');
}
```

Import the method in LWC

```
import getRecordName from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.getRecord'
```

Call this method in `connectedCallback`

```
connectedCallback() {
    getRecordName({ recordId: this.recordId, objectApiName: this.objectApiName})
    .then(result => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
        debugger;
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.displayError(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
    });
```